# MVP Implementation in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am looking into MVP architecture Implementation in a flutter. and I have implemented one.

View Model:

```dart
class AuthenticationViewModel {
   String phone;
   bool isEmailValidate;

   AuthenticationViewModel(){
      phone = null;
      isEmailValidate = false;
   }
}
```

Presenter:

```dart
class AuthenticationPresenter{
    void onValidatePhone(String value){}
    set authenticateView(AuthenticationView value) {}
}

class BasicAuthenticationPresenter implements AuthenticationPresenter {
   AuthenticationViewModel _authenticationViewModel;
   AuthenticationView _authenticationView;

   BasicAuthenticationPresenter() {
     this._authenticationViewModel = new AuthenticationViewModel();
   }

   @override
   void onValidatePhone(String value) {
     if(PhoneValidator.isPhoneValidate(value))
       this._authenticationView.validatePhone(true, value);
     else
       this._authenticationView.validatePhone(false, null);
   }

  @override
  set authenticateView(AuthenticationView value) {
    _authenticationView = value;
    this._authenticationView.refreshAuthentication(this._authenticationViewModel);
  }
}
```

View:

```dart
class AuthenticationView {
   void refreshAuthentication(AuthenticationViewModel value) {
      print("refreshCounter not implemented yet"); 
   }
   void validatePhone(bool value, String phone) { 
     print("validatePhone not implemented yet"); 
   }
}
```

Component:

```dart
class Authentication extends StatefulWidget {
  final AuthenticationPresenter presenter;

   Authentication(this.presenter);

   @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      return _AuthenticationState();
   }
}

class _AuthenticationState extends State<Authentication> implements AuthenticationView{
  AuthenticationViewModel _viewModel;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.widget.presenter.counterView = this;
  }

 @override
  void  refreshAuthentication(AuthenticationViewModel viewModel) {
    setState(() {
      this._viewModel = viewModel;
    });
  }

  @override
  void validatePhone(bool value, String phone) async {
    // TODO: implement validatePhone
    setState(() {
      _viewModel.phone = phone;
      _viewModel.isPhoneValidate = value;
    });
  }
}
```

The trouble is when I try to check phone validation by onValidatePhone method in the presenter, didn't execute what is inside on this._authenticationView.validatePhone like it's stilled null.
And this trouble happened just when I open the layout by `Navigator.pushNamed(context, pageNavigate);`
if I opened it directly from the Main function everything works fine.

```
MaterialApp(
  routes: routes,
  title: 'DawiDari',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: AppColors.primaryGreen,
  ),
  home: new Authentication(new BasicAuthenticationPresenter())
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries finally, I found a solution and if someone has a solution better he can post it because I want the best way to build an MVP architecture.

I have changed Presenter to:

```dart
class AuthenticationPresenter{
    void onValidatePhone(String value){}
}

class BasicAuthenticationPresenter implements AuthenticationPresenter {
   AuthenticationViewModel _authenticationViewModel;
   AuthenticationView _authenticationView;

   BasicAuthenticationPresenter(this._authenticationView) {
     this._authenticationViewModel = new AuthenticationViewModel();
     this._authenticationView.refreshAuthentication(this._authenticationViewModel);
   }

   @override
   void onValidatePhone(String value) {
     if(PhoneValidator.isPhoneValidate(value))
       this._authenticationView.validatePhone(true, value);
     else
       this._authenticationView.validatePhone(false, null);
   }
}
```

and I also changed Component to:

```dart
class Authentication extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      return _AuthenticationState();
   }
}

class _AuthenticationState extends State<Authentication> implements AuthenticationView{
  AuthenticationPresenter presenter;
  AuthenticationViewModel _viewModel;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    presenter = new BasicAuthenticationPresenter(this);
  }

 @override
  void  refreshAuthentication(AuthenticationViewModel viewModel) {
    setState(() {
      this._viewModel = viewModel;
    });
  }

  @override
  void validatePhone(bool value, String phone) async {
    // TODO: implement validatePhone
    setState(() {
      _viewModel.phone = phone;
      _viewModel.isPhoneValidate = value;
    });
  }
}
```